# apostrophecms apostrophe-search throws template warning for apostrophe-attachment

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have set up an apostrophe-search page on my apostrophe cms project. Everything is working fine until it lists pdf files I have uploaded using the apostrophe-files module. The link still populates with a url, allowing me to download the pdf file, but in the console I'm getting the error:

> Template warning: Impossible to retrieve the attachment url since it is missing, a default icon has been set. Please fix this ASAP!

This error is coming from

```
/lib/modules/apostrophe-attachments/lib/api.js
```

but I am at a loss as to why it is getting thrown at all - the file exists, it has a url, I can download it, it shows up in search results.

I haven't touched any of the boilerplate code for apostrophe-attachments, nor for apostrophe-search.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: I think you might have a doc of type `apostrophe-file` which somehow has no `attachment` property. Can  you check your database via mongo shell? `db.aposDocs.findOne({type: 'apostrophe-file', attachment: { $exists: 0 })`

Comment: Hi Tom and thanks for the suggestion. Sadly though, running your mongo command (plus an extra sneaky curly bracket) returns `null`.

Comment: I see. Can you set up a project with instructions to duplicate the issue?